# how to prepend an html element to each element of a html collection using jquery each method?

Tags: jquery, font-awesome

I have some `li` elements, and I want to add to each one of them a font awesome icon. (I could do it directly in the HTML code, but I want to learn to do it more dynamically). I tried this:

HTML:

```
<ul class="willHaveArrows">
    <li>text 1</li>
    <li>text 2</li>
    <li>text 3</li>
    <li>text 4</li>
    <li>text 5</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
$('.willHaveArrows li').each((i, e) => e.prepend("<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span>"))
```

However, instead of getting a `span` element prepended to the `li` (showing the font awesome arrow), I just get the string added to it. like this:

```
<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span> text1
<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span> text2
<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span> text3
<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span> text4
<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span> text5
```

How can I accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because the second argument of `.each()` (`e` in your case) is not a jQuery element, but a standard HTML element. The non-jQuery [prepend method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/prepend) does not read HTML strings as elements.

If you want to go the jQuery route (*see below first!*) you won't need an `.each()` because jQuery's `.prepend()` acts upon all items in the collection by default.

```
$(".willHaveArrows > li").prepend("<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span>");
```

```js
$(".willHaveArrows > li").prepend("<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="willHaveArrows">
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
  <li>text 5</li>
</ul>
```

Though I should point out that **JavaScript (especially jQuery) is overkill for this task**. It is much more efficient to do this in CSS.

```
.willHaveArrows > li::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f061";    /* Unicode value from FontAwesome */
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```css
.willHaveArrows > li::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f061";
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul class="willHaveArrows">
  <li>text 1</li>
  <li>text 2</li>
  <li>text 3</li>
  <li>text 4</li>
  <li>text 5</li>
</ul>
```

<sup>**For those using FontAwesome 5 and above**, the CSS font declaration will be `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free"`.</sup>

Unicode values (like `f061` in the CSS above) can be retrieved from the documentation page for the corresponding icon ([`arrow-right`](https://fontawesome.com/icons/arrow-right?style=solid)). FontAwesome also provides a [**Unicode Cheatsheet**](https://fontawesome.com/cheatsheet) for quick reference.

Answer (score 0):

I would firstly check if `<li>` contains the Font Awesome icon, then I would use [html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

```
$(".willHaveArrows li").each(function() {
    if (!$(this).find(".fa").length) {
        $(this).html("<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span>" + $(this).html())
    }
})
```

and in one-liner:

```
$(".willHaveArrows li").each(function(){$(this).find(".fa").length||$(this).html("<span class='fa fa-arrow-right'></span>"+$(this).html())});
```